# Кнопка Copy не работает в WebView в Android

Tags: android, веб-программирование, webview

В своем приложение я использую `webView`, где отображаю веб-сайт, в веб-сайте есть кнопка copy, при нажатии на эту кнопку ничего не копируется, все остальные кнопки работают как надо. Как можно исправить эту проблему?

Код который пробовала, но это не решило проблему:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setMinimumFontSize(1);
        webView.getSettings().setMinimumLogicalFontSize(1);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
```

Comment: можно в хроме открывать нужную ссылку и все)) я вчера тоже столкнулся с подобной проблемой, и понял что учесть все в этом вью для полноценного замещения браузера очень сложно. советую вам открывать через браузер и мороки намного меньше и удобнее.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko мне нужно открыть именно в WebView, со всеми остальными проблемами уже разобралась, осталась только эта кнопка